# How to return a new promise instead of an error on a failed ajax request in Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

I have a function which creates a `deferred` object. On `fail` I'm calling a fallback function, which in turn creates and returns it's own `deferred/promise` object. I would like to return the result of this **fallback-**`deferred` but I'm only able to return the `error` on my initial call.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
 // method call
 init.fetchConfigurationFile(
      storage,
      "gadgets",
      gadget.getAttribute("data-gadget-id"),
      pointer
  ).then(function(fragment) {
      console.log("gotcha");
      console.log(fragment);
  }).fail(function(error_should_be_fragment) {
      console.log("gotcha not");
      console.log(error_should_be_fragment);
  });
```

My `fetchConfiguration` call tries to load from localstorage and falls back to loading from file if the document/attachment I need is not in localstorage.

```
  init.fetchConfigurationFile = function (storage, file, attachment, run) {
    return storage.getAttachment({"_id": file, "_attachment": attachment})
      .then(function (response) {
        return jIO.util.readBlobAsText(response.data);
      })
      .then(function (answer) {
        return run(JSON.parse(answer.target.result))
      })
      .fail(function (error) {
        // PROBLEM
        console.log(error);
        if (error.status === 404 && error.id === file) {
          return init.getFromDisk(storage, file, attachment, run);
        }
      });
  };
```

My problem is I can catch the `404` allright, but instead of returning the `error` object, I would like to return the promise generated by `init.getFromDisk`.

**Question**:
Is it possible to return the result of my `getFromDisk` call in the error handler? If not, how would I have to structure my calls so that I'm always returning a promise to my first method call?

Thanks for help!

**SOLUTION**:
Thanks for the help! Fixed it like this:

```
 init.fetchConfigurationFile(
      storage,
      "gadgets",
      gadget.getAttribute("data-gadget-id"),
      pointer
    ).always(function(fragment) {
      console.log("gotcha");
      console.log(fragment);
    });

init.fetchConfigurationFile = function (storage, file, attachment, run) {
  return storage.getAttachment({"_id": file, "_attachment": attachment})
    .then(function (response) {
      return jIO.util.readBlobAsText(response.data);
    })
    .then(
      function (answer) {
        return run(JSON.parse(answer.target.result));
      },
      function (error) {
        if (error.status === 404 && error.id === file) {
          return init.getFromDisk(storage, file, attachment, run);
        }
      }
    );
};
```

Comment: Why `.then(...).then()`? Try deleting the 1st `.then()` and changing the 1st callback of the 2nd `.then()` to `function (response) { var answer = jIO.util.readBlobAsText(response.data); return run(JSON.parse(answer.target.result)); }`. The nett effect should be identical.

Comment: Agree. Currently it only works like with `then().then()`, since the plugin I'm using requires this syntax. I already mentioned to the author (colleague) one `then()` would make things easier.

Comment: OK, `.then().then()` will work fine but simplifying to one `.then()` will be more readable (as I'm sure you already know).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.fail()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) always returns the original promise.

You should call [`then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) with a failure callback to allow chaining:

```
.then(undefined, function(error) {
    return ...;
});
```

Before jQuery 1.8, use `.pipe()` instead.